# O que significa o //= no Python?

Tags: python, operadores, sintaxe

Alguém sabe me dizer o que significa o //= no python?

Na linha 8 desse código tem o uso dele.

```
n = int(input("Digite um numero menor que 10: "))

aux, reverso = n, 0

while aux != 0:
    dig = aux%10
    reverso = reverso*10 + aux%10
    aux //= 10

if reverso == n:
    print(n, "é palidromo ")
else:
    print(n, "não é palídromo")
```

Answer (score 7):

Esse é um dos que chamamos de [*In-place operators*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators), que são operadores executados em conjunto com o operador de atribuição sobre o próprio objeto (por isso o termo *in-place*).

Neste caso, o operador `//=` nada mais é que o operador `//` em conjunto com o operador de atribuição `=`, sendo equivalente a:

```
aux = aux // 10
```

Foi definido os operadores de atribuição justamente para evitar a necessidade de digitar o mesmo objeto duas vezes dentro da expressão.

O operador `//` é conhecido como *floor division* pois retorna apenas a parte inteira da divisão entre os operandos, diferente do operador `/`, denominado *true division*, que retorna um número com ponto flutuante. É interessante notar que implicitamente o operador `//` irá chamar o método `__ifloordiv__` do seu objeto, então, ao fazer `aux //= 10` você implicitamente está executando `aux.__ifloordiv__(10)`, ou ainda `operator.ifloordiv(aux, 10)`.

Outros operadores *in-place* são:

- `x += y`, equivalente a `x = x + y`
- `x &= y`, equivalente a `x = x and y`
- `x <<= y`, equivalente a `x = x << y`
- `x %= y`, equivalente a `x = x % y`
- `x *= y`, equivalente a `x = x * y`
- `x @= y`, equivalente a `x = x @ y`
- `x |= y`, equivalente a `x = x | y`
- `x **= y`, equivalente a `x = x **y`
- `x >>= y`, equivalente a `x = x >> y`
- `x -= y`, equivalente a `x = x - y`
- `x /= y`, equivalente a `x = x / y`
- `x ^= y`, equivalente a `x = x ^y`

Comment: +1 ótima resposta, porém qual o nome  e função do `x @= y` ?vi na documentação que que chama o método `__imatmul__`, mas na prática seria útil para?

Comment: @LuizAugusto É para multiplicação matricial (matrizes). Que eu saiba nenhum objeto nativo utiliza esse operador, mas ele existe justamente para permitir que seja sobrecarregado em classes definidas pelo usuário.

Answer (score 5):

O `//`, chamada de **floor division**, ignora o resto de uma divisão e retorna apenas o inteiro do resultado. Por exemplo:

```
x = 17 // 3 
print(x)
>> 5
```

Outros exemplos:

```
5 / 2 = 2.5        (2)
5 / 7 = 0.714285   (0)
5 / -6 = −0.8333   (-1 já que é o inteiro mais próximo de -0.833333)
5 / -2 = −2.5      (-3)
5 / -3 = −1.6666   (-2)
```

O Floor division é o inverso do **módulo** (`%`) que printa o resto de uma divisão.

```
x = 17 % 3 
print(x)
>> 2
```

Documentação do [floor division aqui](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/introduction.html) e do [módulo aqui](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)

Answer (score 3):

É o mesmo que `aux = aux // 10`

`//` Divisão inteira. O python divide, retorna um inteiro e aplica a função `.floor`(arredonda para baixo) ao resultado .

Comment: Referencia na documentação: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations e em outras perguntas do Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15194137/5846448

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a sua dúvida, o operador `//` do Python, quer dizer que faz a extração da parte inteira de uma divisão, por exemplo:

```
>>> 10//9 resultado: 1;
```

Agora `//=10`, eu entendo que é o mesmo disto `+=10` em programação, espero ter ajudado.